# Improving my print_r Algorithm

Tags: php, debugging

Well guys, it's a simple question (more than a question i'ts a challenge).

When i develop large applications its really hard to track how the arrays are working (in arrays of more than 3 dimensions, or arrays that contain arrays that contain arrays, etc...)

So, the PHP developers have the print_r($array) function. The format that this deliver the information its helpful if your array is no longer than 1 dimension or a couple of variables... so, i programmed a little function that parses arrays (and arrays of arrays) using a little of CSS and HTML.

I'll share the function for you, but more important than that, is to improve it, to make it more friendly (avoid use images or that... just a simple function that dont user other files to work with), or if there's something (a library or a function) that i don't know that help in this matter?

Thanks in advance.

The function:

```
function print_a($array,$prefix = "")
{
    if(is_array($array))
    {
        foreach($array as $value => $valor)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo " <td>";
            if(is_array($valor))
            {
                echo "<div style='background-color: #C7E792;height: 5px; width: 100%; padding: 5px;'><strong>ARRAY: $value</strong></div>";
                echo $prefix." ";
                print_a($valor,$prefix."&nbsp;&nbsp;> ");
            }
            else
            {
                if(!is_numeric($value))
                {
                    echo "<div style='background-color: #FFFFFF;height: 10px; width: 100%;'>";
                    echo $prefix;
                    echo "<b>".$value."</b> = ".$valor."<br/>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }
        }
    } else { echo "It's not an array =( !"; }
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: you could use Zend_Debug class in you're app , and call it Zend_Debug::dump($array); it will display multi-dimentinal arrays and well nicer than print_r would . Aditionaly you could use var_dump($array); but it's not realy html , if you go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php you'll see user comments that use var_dump to fill a html table from a multidimentional array .

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the format not being helpful for multi-dimensional arrays; I've always found `print_r` to be very well formatted. You do need to wrap it in `<pre>` tags if its in an HTML page though, or it'll all appear on one line, which does make it a lot harder to read. Perhaps that's what you're seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recomment using [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/). Krumo does all you want and more.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend trying http://www.xdebug.org/.  You can customize the depth and style of your `var_dump` and `print_r` output.